# Force the Django admin to display in English

Tags: django, django-admin

My website is not in English, but I want the Django admin to be shown only in English.

How can I force the Django admin to display in English regardless of `LANGUAGE_CODE` settings?

Comment: Show some code to see what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know there is no out of the box settings for this functionality, but you can easily code it in a middleware. Add this code to a middleware.py file to one of your apps:

```
from django.utils import translation

class AdminLocaleMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.path.startswith('/admin'):
            translation.activate("en")
            request.LANGUAGE_CODE = translation.get_language()
```

Add AdminLocaleMiddleware to your settings after LocaleMiddleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    ...
    "django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware",
    "your_app.middleware.AdminLocaleMiddleware",
    ...
]
```

Comment: Instead of using `request.path` you can also test `request.resolver_match.app_name`

Answer (score 4):

For **Django 2.0** :

```
from django.utils import translation


class AdminLocaleMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, process_request):
        self.process_request = process_request

    def __call__(self, request):

        if request.path.startswith('/admin'):
            translation.activate("en")
            request.LANGUAGE_CODE = translation.get_language()

        response = self.process_request(request)

        return response
```

Comment: Please provide some additional explanation with you answer and do not just paste code (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: How is this different from the answer by @ozren1983 ?

Comment: @ozren1983  for Django 1, 
this answer for Django 2:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/middleware/